# Azure Inbound security rules not working for fix Source port

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to connect SQL Server from local machine.

Following inbound security rule is not working with the fix source port. But it works with * for source port.

What is wrong with this setup?

[image: Rule Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, 1433 is the port on the server, not necessarily the port on the client.  Depending on the client being used, you may have any random high order port in use to make the SQL connection.  Only use 1433 as the source if you know that the app/client you are using uses 1433 only.

Comment: I am using SQL Management studio for connect the database using the port with IP as the server name (ex:13.94.200.55,1433).

Comment: Yes, that port is the server port.  Not the client port.  You can use netstat -b -a to determine which source port is in use (source = client)

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Server firewall prevents all access to your database server until you specify which machine or computer have permission to access your database externally, by **[Allowing IP Address](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/)** to your Azure SQL SERVER. The firewall grants access based on the originating IP address of your each request.